# Keyboard shortcut to get latest version in Visual Studio

Tags: visual-studio, keyboard-shortcuts

I want a keyboard shortcut to Get Latest Version (Recursive) of the current solution in Visual Studio 2012. We are using TFS.

I've tried to map

```
File.GetLatestSolutionFiles
File.GetLatestVersion
File.TfsGetLatestVersion
```

but nothing happens. Any ideas?

As a workaround I've also tried, and failed, to map a keyboard shortcut to:

```
Tools.shell """c:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio 11.0\Common7\IDE\TF.exe""" get $/OUR/REPOSITORY/Main /recursive
```

This is the command I want a keyboard shortcut to:
[image]

Comment: Impossible to answer this accurately when you don't mention what source control you use and how it is integrated with VS.

Comment: It won't help you much, but I tested 'File.TfsGetLatestVersion' and CTRL+! as a shortcut with VS 2012 (and VS 2010) and TFS 2010, and it works fine for me. Could it be local to your setup?

Comment: That's the exact setup that we're running! Are you using ReSharper as well? Not that it should matter.

Comment: I do have R# V5 installed (and the assemblies are loaded in VS adress space), but I leave it the suspended state (you known, when it does not eat the whole memory), but only in VS2010, not in VS2012. PS: don't forget to add the @ when you send comment to someone, I was notified of yours.

Answer (score 9):

Alt-V P Home Alt-F R L

or

Alt-V P Home Menu L (This is how I do it every day)

A shorter solution is by binding one of the commands you listed; How did you try that, exactly?

Comment: I tried to bind each of them to crtl+shift+' and nothing happened. Then I bound it to OpenFile and that worked so it isn't a problem with the shortcut.

Comment: Try binding just TfsGetLatestVersion; I'm pretty sure that if you have conflicting bindings, only the first one found will be fired. Also, are you using TFS or a different VCS?

Comment: We are using TFS. Now I tried TfsGetLatestVersionDynamicSilent and then something happens. Just have to verify that it actually gets latest on the solution and not just the current file.

Comment: "All files are up to date." even though there are changes in another project (in the same solution). TfsGetLatestVersionDynamicSilent wasn't it.

Comment: Well, if my answer and right-clicking and selecting the menu command works, but File.TfsGetLatestVersion doesn't, I'm not sure what to say. They correspond, as far as I know.

Comment: I don't know what I did wrong before but now it actually happens something when I do `File.TfsGetLatestVersion`. The problem is that it seems to only get the latest version of the current open file. Not for all files in the project and certainly not for all files in the solution.

Comment: I see the same behavior; this may be why I decided some time ago to go with my "manual" solution. There's probably not an available command to get all the solution files. File.GetLatestSolutionFiles seems like it would be the ticket, but that and File.GetLatestVersion don't work for me with TFS.

Comment: I've assigned this to F7 using AutoHotKey: `#IfWinActive Microsoft Visual Studio ⤶ F7::Send !v p {home} !f r l ⤶ #IfWinActive`, where ⤶ is a new line.

Answer (score 6):

In 2012 you can simply just do "ALT-F R L"

Comment: The gets the latest version of the currently open file. I'm looking for a shortcut that gets latest on the complete solution.

Answer (score 5):

The command is **`TfsGetLatestVersionDynamicSilent`**. The way that the command works is based on the `Solution Explorer`.

1. Set your key binding in `Options > Environment > Keyboard`.
   [image: TfsGetLatestVersionDynamicSilent]
2. Select what you want to update in the `Solution Explorer`. Here, I'm selecting the `Solution`.
   [image: Solution]
3. Then, hit your key binding, and voila! Now, you got the latest from TFS for your `Solution`.
   [image: All files are up to date.]

Answer (score 3):

```
C:\Foo\Bar\Main>tf get . /recursive
```

from Visual Studio Command Prompt

**Full example**

Put this in a bat-file:

```
@echo off
call "C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio 11.0\Common7\Tools\VsDevCmd.bat"
cd /d "C:\Foo\Bar\Main"
tf get . /recursive
pause
```

Create a shortcut to the .bat-file on your desktop and assign a global key (I have mine mapped to *CTRL+ALT+G*) to that shortcut. You can assign keys if you right-click the shortcut and choose properties.

Comment: How do I bind that to a keyboard shortcut or at least to a menu item?

Comment: Put the code in a .bat-file, place a shortcut (to the .bat-file) on your desktop, go into properties for that shortcut and assign a keyboard shortcut (I have mine mapped to CTRL+ALT+G). Works like a charm! :)

Comment: Full command line file: `@echo off [return]
call "C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio 11.0\Common7\Tools\VsDevCmd.bat"[return]
cd /d "F:\Projects\tfs\SunHotels\B.Dev\Groups\SunHotels.Groups"[return]
tf get . /recursive[return]
pause` replace `[return]` with a new line. (Mini-markdown does not allow new lines in comments... My bad...)

Comment: I will try this out the coming week. Now I also see why this could work. It's not done with Visual Studio at all, but that's fine by me!

Comment: This works but I found the File Modification Detected dialogs annoying. They also lag behind several seconds.
https://dl.dropboxusercontent.com/u/26840/file_mod_detected.png

It would be much better with a solution integrated in Visual Studio.

Comment: You could install [AutoHotKey](http://www.autohotkey.com/) and use a script that triggers inside VS, executes the batch-file, waits a few seconds and sends Alt+A to the "Update All"-dialog.

Answer (score 2):

Mapping the shortcut through Tools -> Options -> Environment -> Keyboard works. 

  
Steps:

1. Go to Tools menu -> Options.
2. Expand Environment node. Go to Keyboard section
3. Type "tfsget" in "Show commands containing:" text box.
4. Select File.TfsGetLatestVersion from the list of options displayed.
   [image]
5. Select "Press shortcut keys:" text box and enter your keys combination.
6. Click Assign button and make sure that the keys combination shows up in "Shortcuts for selected command:" dropdown.
7. Click Ok button.

To make sure this worked, open Output window (View menu -> Output), clear all messages from it.
[image]

Open the solution in the Solution Explorer, select the solution, project or the file that you need to get the latest for and key in your combination.

If it worked, you will see the message in the output window:
[image]

Answer (score 1):

Modified off @RickardN's answer

Create a file called GetLatest.bat and put it in your program folder.

The file should contain this:

```
@echo off
call "C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio 12.0\Common7\Tools\VsDevCmd.bat"
tf get . /recursive
rem require keypress on error, else pause a few seconds
if %errorlevel% neq 0 pause
if %errorlevel% == 0 choice /C X /T 3 /D X > nul
```

The path to vsdevcmd.bat assumes you are using Visual Studio 2013; change the path depending on your version of Visual Studio.  Now go to Tools->External Tools and Add a new command.  Call it Get Latest.  Set the Command to the path to your .bat file, and set Initial Directory to $(SolutionDir).

You can map the external command to a toolbar button or a shortcut.

Comment: I don't have VS2013. Does this show the File Modification Detected dialog?
https://dl.dropboxusercontent.com/u/26840/file_mod_detected.png

Comment: @JonasElfström If you have the file open in Visual Studio, then yes it will tell you that the file has changed and asks you if you want to reload it.  That's basic Visual Studio functionality - nothing to do with TFS.  The same thing happens if you modify a file that you have open in VS with an external editor like notepad.

Comment: Yes but it isn't instantaneous and those seconds of lag is kind of bothering.

Comment: This works nicely, but it prompts me to enter my TFS credentials each time. Is there any way to avoid that?

Comment: @DanielAlexiuc There's a few solutions to that, including specifying your credentials with -login:username@domain,password on the tfs command https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/Hh190725.aspx

Answer (score 0):

Using Visual Studio Macros, you can setup this macro

```
//go to solution explorer
dte.ExecuteCommand("View.SolutionExplorer");

//1 based indexing so item 1 is the first item, which should be you Solution
dte.Windows.Item(1).Activate();

//perform get on the activated item (which is the solution)
dte.ExecuteCommand("File.TfsGetLatestVersion");
```

Then you just bind that macro to something like cntrl+alt+shift+G

If you are not using Visual Studio Macros i highly recommend them:
[Macros For Visual Studio 13/15/17](https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=VisualStudioPlatformTeam.MacrosforVisualStudio)

Comment: This sounds interesting but I don't have Visual Studio or even Windows now so I can't test if it works. If this gets verified by a reputable source I will consider accepting this answer.